# Barlow rendering difference between Google Fonts example page and usage in a separate page

Tags: css, webfonts, google-webfonts, google-fonts

We're using Barlow, available for free from Google fonts, in a web app. Here's the way a sample phrase looks when rendered on [Google's example page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Barlow?selection.family=Barlow:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i). (If you want to reproduce it, you will need to enter the custom text yourself and adjust the slider to `14px`.)

[image: A sample phrase rendered in Barlow at Google Fonts]

Note, in particular, the distinct space between the bottom of the `i` and its dot above, as well as the clarity of the top part of the `f`.

This is how the same phrase looks when rendered in our app, as reproduced in this [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/neagle/pen/xBWmOZ).

[image: The same sample phrase rendered in Barlow on Code Pen using Google Fonts]

Note the muddy space between the `i` and its dot, as well as the muddy top curve to the `f`.

I've tried looking through all the styles on the elements in question, and I can't find any style that should affect these differently. The network tab clearly shows that the bold version of the font is being loaded; it doesn't look as if this could be faux bold.

This may seem trivial, but we've actually had quite a few complaints about how the font looks in our app, specifically that the bold, lowercase `i` looks like an `l`.

Anyone have an idea what might be happening here?

*Update:* Using Chrome on a Mac; I can confirm the same issue in Firefox. This is on an external display... on a retina there's no problem, as there is way more detail.

Comment: The codepen looks like the top sample for me. What browser/OS combo are you using?

Comment: This is a screen rendering issue. Looks clean to me in the pen too. Your text is 14px, on the small side for text, especially in a mobile device. That combined with the `700` font-weight is contributing the discrepancy in rendering the rasterized pixels. Perhaps bump up the font size a notch?

Comment: @zgood: Using Chrome on a Mac. I updated the question to add that info.

Comment: @Simran That's not an unreasonable suggestion, and we may ask the design team to do that. But I'd like to solve the mystery of why the text appears nicely crisp at that size in Google's example, if possible.

Comment: I have had font rendering issues with Mac in the past. One thing you could try is to download the Barlow font file from google, then use a site like [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create a webfont kit and see if you have better luck with that

Comment: I believe that this particular browser setup runs the truetype font. Have you confirmed that these are loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be [a problem with the source repo](https://github.com/jpt/barlow/issues/50): "hinting got missed in the most recent commit" and the Google specimen (which looked correct) was "actually running an earlier version."

Happily, the maintainer was able to get the problem fixed with a subsequent version.